# How to Mock Eclipse Plugin class with methods?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, mockito, powermock

I have to write a JUnit test case for a method which accepts `Plugin` instance.
Inside the method, I have to get the Plugin Symbolic name using

```
plugin.getBundle().getSymbolicName()
```

I have tried to make a Plugin class mock.

```
Plugin pluginMock = Mockito.mock(Plugin.class);
    Mockito.when(pluginMock.getBundle().getSymbolicName()).thenReturn("com.app.test");
```

This `pluginMock` is injected to `PluginLoggerFactory` class Constructor and inside constructor, it call `pluginMock.getBundle().getSymbolicName()` method.

but I'm facing a `NullPointerExcpetion` because `pluginMock` is null and I can't call `getBundle()` on a Null value.

Please suggest how to mock Plugin class instance.
PS: -  I also tried to call method chaining `Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`

Comment: I don't think that `pluginMock` is null.

Comment: @Kai : it is, i tried

Comment: Next hint: maybe `pluginMock.getBundle()` returns null?

Comment: Eclipse plugins require a lot of initialization, you need to use something like the [JUnit Plug-in Test Launcher](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Flaunchers%2Fjunit_launcher.htm) to test them

Comment: @greg-449 He wants to **completely** mock the plugin object. Why do you need anything else for that?!

Comment: Actually, RETURN_DEEP_STUBS should **exactly** solve your problem. When it doesn't ... you are probably doing something wrong. So please read [mcve] and add the missing information to your question.

Comment: @Kai: i agreed . pluginMock.getBundle() return null.

Comment: @GhostCat: but in my pluginMock object i can find debug information with bundle=null  thats whey i think it give me nullPointerException

Comment: Use Mockito to return a mock object instead of null when calling `pluginMock.getBundle()`.

Comment: @GhostCat : i resolve the issue. the issue with pluginMock.getBundle() method, getBundle() is final and we can't mock final method using Mockito so i have to use PowerMock.

Comment: Eeeeek. Or you step back and think what exactly you intend to achieve (I have to say that because PowerMock and GhostCat dont go together nicely). Beyond that: I thought the newest version of Mockito do support mocking final methods as experimental feature?